# Missing parents error while broadcasting btc transaction

Tags: node.js, transactions, bitcoin, bitcore

My code is as follows for a simple script to generate raw transactions.

```
var path = require('path').dirname(require.main.filename)
var bitcore = require('bitcore-lib')
var fs = require('fs')
var UnspentOutput = bitcore.Transaction.UnspentOutput
const blockchain = require('blockchain.info')

var json = fs.readFileSync(path + '/' + '1MPP77eCzAsCKMjtWzdcNw4XMUxb5ePBeA.json');
obj = JSON.parse(json)

var address = "1C3xRrMetAdz2VSnbuDTnwHj3Dyeo9auk2"
var amount = 1000000 //satoshis
var privkeySet = bitcore.PrivateKey.fromWIF(obj["priv"]);
var cAddr = "1MPP77eCzAsCKMjtWzdcNw4XMUxb5ePBeA"

blockchain.blockexplorer.getUnspentOutputs(cAddr).then(outputs => {
  var utxo = new UnspentOutput({
    "txid" : outputs['unspent_outputs'][0]['tx_hash'],
    "vout" : outputs['unspent_outputs'][0]['tx_output_n'],
    "address" : cAddr,
    "script" : outputs['unspent_outputs'][0]['script'],
    "satoshis" : outputs['unspent_outputs'][0]['value']
  })

  var utxos = [utxo]

  var tx = new bitcore.Transaction()
    .from(utxos)
    .to(address, amount)
    .change(cAddr)
    .fee(10000)
    .sign(privkeySet);

  console.log("transaction = " + tx.verify());
  console.log("Signature = " + tx.isFullySigned());

  console.log(tx)
});
```

However, when I broadcast the raw transaction via blockchain.info, I get the following...

`Missing parents for 62ce2eacfb96368dc7751e023d0890eae2e700c46dce1bd91192be27db6e97e7 while inserting: [872f22da56a21f500b87db1a6361ca228cca6b75913faeb4cb9ce2d19133a185]`

Both `verify` and `isFullySigned` return true.  The raw transaction is as follows...

`010000000185a13391d1e29ccbb4ae3f91756bca8c22ca61631adb870b501fa256da222f87000000006b483045022100d713fbef655d7962731cc672b84a29db25fb274494a783f0d6507a683fd91301022044881127ec59d291d7f0dcf12bc7163be5bcf0d64808d5e8f5fac897e0c40d9401210327efda0447312e9bf7daff4788aa721302cc14778bcbdfb4e679229e985357b9ffffffff0240420f00000000001976a91479387c223f297cad674c523bd44403c1caf666ca88ac7ae90300000000001976a914df9e1e985d57beaafa44c6cafe712f05cddc2db188ac00000000`

Absolutely no idea what's going wrong.  Transaction is signing, the unspent output is good, etc.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try to run again and make sure that isFullySigned return true. If so rewrite the above code for the testnet and publish the testnet priv key. You can use blockr to fetch data from the testnet.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?